# JS RegExp to remove all HTML tags and their content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

For example,  I need to get from this:

```
Before Bold <b>In Bold</b> After Bold
```

To get:

```
Before Bold After Bold.
```

I tried:

```
string.replace(/<.*>.*<\/.*>/,'')
```

But it don't work as expected.

Comment: You are using greedy regexp

Comment: The result has two spaces in between `"Before Bold"` and `"After Bold"`. This is because you only removed the html tag. This is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: `/(<([^>]+)>)/ig` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cB2YJ/1/)... I'd prefer VisioN's method over regex.

Comment: I need to remove the tags, and the innerHTML of all the tags. What adeneo show, only remove the tags. I am don't search for best solution, only something that will work in most scenarios

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, because it didn't remove the `<b>` tag with its contents.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Append the string to an element, and filter by nodetype, only keeping textnodes.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
string.replace(/<([^>]+?)([^>]*?)>(.*?)<\/\1>/ig, "")
```

It worked for me.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fVTU6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    result = "",
    child;

div.innerHTML = str;
child = div.firstChild;

do {
    if (child.nodeType === 3) {
        result += child.nodeValue;
    }
} while (child = child.nextSibling);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You might need to trim double spaces too

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about regex, but using jQuery you can easily just remove the children and return the HTML using a classic one-liner:

```
string = $('<div>').html(string).children().remove().end().html();
```