# Strip tags from a string - HTML5

Tags: javascript, regex, html

The following string is valid HTML in HTM5, even with the `>` in the attribute:

```
'<span src="whatever.png" data-info="hello>there">text</span>';
```

Almost [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499889/remove-html-tags-in-javascript-with-regex) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140211/js-regexp-to-remove-all-html-tags-and-their-content) [proposed](http://devcrapshoot.com/javascript/regular-expression-for-removing-html-tags) before use a variant of:

```
replace( /<.*?>/g, '' )
```

Which fails for this due to the `>` in the attribute.

There is also the option of writing the content to a dummy element and then reading back the `textContent`, but that is horribly slow when dealing with a lot of data.

So, I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions? Removing the attributes - or at least the attribute values with the matching quotes in a first pass regex and then a second pass to strip the tags seems like it might be the way to go, but I can't quite get my head around it!

Comment: A Regular Expression Engine is **not** a Lexer. It's not designed to do such things, and usually fails on edge cases. Yours is just one example. Besides, if you're looking for speed, regex is not the way to go anyway. Parse it yourself.

Comment: The right answer is to not use regex. However, depending on exactly what your expected inputs are, you might be able to pull it off. For example, for *your particular example*, you could look for the text between `>` and `</` but that's not going to be a general solution. Use an actual html parser.

Comment: And using Jquery, this would be as simple as `$('<span src="whatever.png" data-info="hello>there">text</span>').text()`. But perhaps you can elaborate on what your tried to do when you `writing the content to a dummy element and then reading back the textContent` and what you define as "horribly slow" and what is "a lot of data"?

Comment: Another way: http://jsfiddle.net/quhpek00/2/

Comment: At least you could link this to a regex that has half a chance (not that crappy one). `<(?:(?:/?\w+\s*/?)|(?:\w+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`

Answer (score -2):

I believe this regex should work for your purpose:

```
/<([^\"\'>]*|\"([^"\\]|\\.)*\"|\'([^'\\]|\\.)*\')*>/g
```

Essentially, it matches any character other than `"`, `'` or `>`, or it matches `"` or `'` followed by any characters followed by another `"` or `'`.

Just use it in the same way as you did in the original question - `string.replace(/<([^\"\'>]*|\"([^"\\]|\\.)*\"|\'([^'\\]|\\.)*\')*>/g, '');`

Comment: This doesn't work. `"<span>test</span>".replace(/<([^\"\'>]*|\"[^"]*\"|\'[^']*\')*>/, '');` => `"test</span>"`

Comment: @meagar sorry, I forgot to add the global flag to the example. It should work now.

Comment: It still doesn't work. `'<span src="\\"what">test</span>'.replace(/<([^\"\'>]*|\"[^"]*\"|\'[^']*\')*>/g, '');` => `"<span src="\"what">test"`

Comment: @meagar I've updated it again to take account of escaped variables (they hadn't even crossed my mind when making that regex though)